# How to create vlan for admin?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, switching, packet-tracer

I wanted create a separate vlan for admin and give access to other vlan , so what is the procedure or method to do it?[image: Screenshot of my pkt file]

Comment: You need a router to route between VLANs.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there any other way to create without using a router?

Comment: You can create separate VLANs but you will not be able to give access to other VLANs without a router.

Comment: Create a management Vlan  and enable inter-Vlan routing which ensures communication between different Vlan . further to control tràffic among different Vlans access-list need to configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers are what route packets between networks, hence the name *router*. Switches will switch frames on the same network. To get traffic from one network to another network, you need a router.

A layer-3 switch is a layer-2 switch with a routing module in it, and it can route traffic between VLANs because it has a router in it. You could use layer-3 switches, rather than layer-2 switches, but your layer-2 switches cannot route traffic between networks.